# LINK in React in Vreact-router-dom v6 K does not work

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a simple code with links from page to page in React,
And for some unknown reason the code does not work.
This is my APP code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import WellcomePage from './WellcomePage';
import BuyPage from './BuyPage';
import NewUserPage from './NewUserPage';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Trading App</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/buy">Buy</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/newuser">New User</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" caseSensitive={false} element={<WellcomePage/>} />
          <Route exact path="/buy" caseSensitive={false} element={<BuyPage/>} />
          <Route exact path="/newuser" caseSensitive={false} element={<NewUserPage/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

this is my code in index.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I tried to change in index.js to:

```
**import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'**
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <**BrowserRouter**>
    <App />
  </**BrowserRouter**>
);
```

but nothing,The code is comppiled but on the page I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVSfy.png)
someone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to a typo in your App.js code. You have a typo in the prop element for the /buy route. You wrote **elemnent** instead of **element**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I fixed it, but unfortunately the page doesn't show any error but it doesn't show anything. can you help me? 
~